# In view of the frozen flux theorem, why don't stars have much stronger magnetic fields?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, plasma-physics, stars

According to the frozen flux theorem or [Alfvén's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alfv%C3%A9n%27s_theorem), the magnetic field in a plasma is frozen into the plasma and must move along with it.  That is, in an ideal plasma, the magnetic flux through a co-moving surface in the plasma is conserved.  It follows that when a plasma is compressed or expanded, the magnetic flux density must change proportionately.  This fact is significant in core collapse supernovas, where it [provides](https://adsabs.harvard.edu/full/2009IAUS..259...61S) one possible (though probably not fully sufficient) mechanism for the formation of ultra-strong magnetic fields in young neutron stars.

But if one tries to calculate the expected magnetic field strength for a newborn star after it forms from the interstellar plasma, it becomes apparent that the result is much higher than what we observe.  For example, suppose that a star forms from a molecular cloud with density $10^6 \text{ atoms/cm}^3$.  For the sun, this implies a cloud volume of about $10^{45} \text{ m}^3$.  Then as the cloud collapses, the magnetic field ought to increase by a factor on the order of $(10^{45} \text{ m}^3)^{2/3} / (2r_{\odot})^2 \approx 5 \times 10^{11}$.

This is not observed.  The interstellar magnetic field strength is typically about $10^{-5}$ G while the magnetic field strengths of T Tauri stars and other strongly magnetized young stars top out at $10^3$ to $10^4$ G.  Clearly stars do have much stronger magnetic fields than the interstellar medium, but the difference is not 11 orders of magnitude.  So what happens to the "missing" magnetic flux?

Comment: A few quick notes:  Young stars tend to be more magnetic than when they age (before they die/collapse).  Also, this approximation assumes that 100% of the material initially forming a star is ionized and magnetized.  There is almost certainly a large fraction of particles that are electrically neutral when a star first forms.  There's a fun homework problem where you can try to balance gravitational potential with total pressure (thermal + magnetic) and if the material has too much magnetic field initially, you get no star...